# AVAudioRecorder is always null

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been trying to record audio in xamarin forms there was no direct way to do it so i was trying to achieve it through custom rendering and i have followed the example from [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/record_sound/).

**// AVAudioRecorder Creation**

```
        //set up the NSObject Array of values that will be combined with the keys to make the NSDictionary
        NSObject[] values = new NSObject[]
        {
            NSNumber.FromFloat (16000.0f), //Sample Rate
            NSNumber.FromInt32 ((int)AudioToolbox.AudioFormatType.MPEG4AAC), //AVFormat
            NSNumber.FromInt32 (1), //Channels
            NSNumber.FromInt32 (16), //PCMBitDepth  
            NSNumber.FromBoolean (false), //IsBigEndianKey
            NSNumber.FromBoolean (false) //IsFloatKey
        };

        //Set up the NSObject Array of keys that will be combined with the values to make the NSDictionary
        NSObject[] keys = new NSObject[]
        {
            AVAudioSettings.AVSampleRateKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVFormatIDKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
            AVAudioSettings.AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey
        };

        //Set Settings with the Values and Keys to create the NSDictionary
        settings = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys (values, keys);

        //Set recorder parameters
        recorder = AVAudioRecorder.Create(url, new AudioSettings(settings), out error);
```

However in the code **"recorder = AVAudioRecorder.Create(url, new AudioSettings(settings), out error);"** is always null

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Whats in the error ?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException, bcuz recorder is null @BugFinder

Comment: that wont be why.. error is telling you that it failed. What is in "AudioSettings" function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have fixed it by myself, made this working by changing the audio settings as follows

```
    `var settings = new AudioSettings
        {
            SampleRate = 44100.0f,
            Format = AudioFormatType.LinearPCM,
            NumberChannels = 1,
            LinearPcmBitDepth = 16,
            AudioQuality = AVAudioQuality.High,
        };`
```